# To replace or update a particular column value in a format file using a for loop or command in .cmd file

Tags: windows, batch-file, format, command, bcp

I'm generating a format file using BCP command as below.

```
BCP    %DATABASE%..Table format NUL -cn -f Format_File.fmt -t -U%sqlid% -P%password% -S%server% -o..\log\test.out -e..\log\test.err
```

I need the native datatype of the columns, hence using `-cn`

But the prefix length for all the columns does not start with `0`

How do I update the format file to set the prefix length column to `0` using a command or how to generate a format file with native datatype & prefix length starting from `0` for all the columns.

[image: Prefix length column as attached in the image.]

I tried the below command, but it's still unable to update the prefix length column to `0`.

```bash
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims= " %%i in (%FILEPATH%Format_File.fmt) do (set %%i=0 in %FILEPATH%Format_File.fmt)
```